# Safari multiple file upload Content Length getting 0 in uploadifive

Tags: browser, safari, uploadifive

I'm trying to get uploadifive to work in Safari. My script works great with Chrome and Firefox.

However, if I select multiple files at once from the dialog box or via drag n drop, the content length of each file is 0 on the server. This problem does not occur if I upload the files one by one.

I'm using Uploadifive v1.1.1, Safari 5.1.7 and .NET 3.5 with ASP.NET MVC 3.

how to resolve this?